# Element shape is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to place a shape element inside a LinearLayout in an XML I use as a layout.
But the shape isn't displayed and I don't know how to get this.

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView...>

            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="190sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25sp">
                <solid android:color="#199fff"/>
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#444444"/>
            </shape>


        </LinearLayout>
```

I get the message "Element shape is not allowed here" when I place the mouse over "shape".

Comment: You should use shape in drawable and use that drawable in layout

Answer (score 4):

Shape needs to go in its own XML file in the `drawable` folder. Then you can assign that drawable to be the background of a view:

```
<View
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/your_xml_name_here"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="190sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25sp" />
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Do you know how I can change the color of the shape from my layout and also programatically?

Comment: Take a look around stackoverflow. I know that question has been asked before.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed, shapes are imutable and you need use one shape for each case